# I don't understand how the author arrived at this answer

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image: Example from Textbook]

So we have the amount of 1 element subsets from a set of 13 C(13,1), the amount of 1 element subsets from a set of 12 C(12,1). I'm assuming this comes from the fact that choosing cards of the same suit guarantees the number of card x =/= number of card y, and then we multiply by the amount of 3 element subsets we can form from cards numbered x and amount of 2 element subsets of cards numbered y. Is this part just the enumeration of how many hands there are that are full houses? And dividing by the total amount of 5 card hands gives us probability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the rank of the set $(_{13}C_1)$ and the three suits $(_4C_3)$, then choose the rank of the pair from what's left $(_{12}C_1)$ and the two suits $(_4C_2)$.  (The numerator is the number of possible five-card hands that are full houses.)

Then divide by the total number of hands.

As an aside, note that it's $(_{13}C_1) \cdot (_{12}C_1)$ and not $_{13}C_2$; the reason is that kings over eights is distinct from eights over kings.